# Cocoa : Repport click on dock icon

Tags: cocoa, dock

Is there a way to report every mouse click on the application dock icon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not completely safe (also activated by double-click on the application itself),
but definitely the most easy way to implement:

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
```

Quote from [NSApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> These events are sent whenever the Finder reactivates an already running application because someone double-clicked it again or used the dock to activate it.

Comment: I already got that one. I use it to popup a nsmenu. But once to menu is open I get no call on that function.

Comment: My mistake. If `applicationShouldHandleReopen` isn't called it's because the menu is kind of modal.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest an alternative solution to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11334006/4216175) provided by [Anne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388037/anne), which avoids conflicting with the event in which the user double clicks on the application icon, instead of on the dock icon.

Thus, I suggest to use

`- (BOOL)applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender;`

See also the [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/1428444-applicationshouldopenuntitledfil?language=objc).